# ng-class applied on pageload, expression is untrue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I'm trying to apply a class to the parent tr of a td that holds a checkbox element. The code works fine, except that the first time the page the loads, the tr already has the class applied, even though the checkbox is unchecked. If i click on the tr element once, the style is removed, and then the element functions as expected. Why is the class getting picked up on page load?
The code:

```
<tr ng-click="isChecked = !isChecked" ng-class="{'hovered': isChecked}">
          <td class=""><input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" /></td>
          <td >Accountability</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: where do you set `isChecked`? Maybe it's true on page load.

Comment: Doesn't the model control the truthyness of the expression? If the element is unchecked, shouldn't the expression be untrue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the controller code as well. It seem to be working when I created this JSBin for the same scenario: https://jsbin.com/saqube/edit?html,css,js,output

I think there might be some issue in your controller or angularjs version

Comment: Good call, thank you! I should've ran the isolated code myself. I now realize I already had another scope of the same name!